# Unable to run RPC programs using rpcgen

Tags: compiler-construction, rpc

I have just started learning about RPC and the rpcgen compiler. I am using the FreeBSD OS and trying to implement a simple program that prints "Hello World" to the console using RPC. 
I first created the '.x' file and using rpcgen, obtained the client and server stubs. Also, I am using both server and client code on the same machine for now. The whole code compiles fine but when I run the program like this: "./firsttry localhost", it outputs the following error: "RPC: Program not registered". What am I doing wrong here? Could it be a problem with the code or is my implementation incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all, check if "rpcbind" is installed, if not install it first as :

   ```
   ~$ sudo apt-get install rpcbind
   ```
2. Then run your server code with superuser permissions as

   ```
    ~$ sudo ./firsttry localhost
   ```
3. There won't be any error now.

Note : instead of writing server and client code by yourself, use the strength of **rpcgen** . While compiling your .x file, try

```
 ~$ rpcgen -a filename.x
```

It will auto-generate all the files. Just few changes are required(in the server and client side codes) . Try it, it's time and effort saving .